# jQuery determine which element called function

Tags: jquery

Suppose I have

```
$('#routingNumber').removeClass(validationClass('#routingNumber'));
```

(Where `validationClass()` is a regex that returns a class that determines the validation.)

Is there any way to trace that `validationClass()` was called on $("routingNumber") without explicity passing in the parameter `#routingNmber`

Phrased differently, is there anyway that the function `validationClass()` can know it should perform the regex on `#routingNumber`

I want to do this for ease of use, and in some cases it will be necessary.

Note: using `$(this)` as the parameter wont work, since the click event to remove the class is not bound to `#rountingNumber`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to define a new function like this:

```
$.fn.removeValidationClass = function(){
    $(this).removeClass(validationClass($(this)));
    return $(this);
}
```

The value of $(this) will be the `#routingNumber` div in your example if called like this:

```
$('#routingNumber').removeValidationClass();
```

Comment: this is actually the route i took (that is, to make a plugin).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you can use the (undocumented, as of now) `selector` property exposed by jQuery objects. This property will return the selector originally passed to `$()`:

```
var obj = $("#routingNumber");
obj.removeClass(validationClass(obj.selector));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#routingNumber').removeClass(function() {
          return validationClass($(this));
});
```

or

```
$('.validateme').removeClass(function() {
          return validationClass($(this));
});
```

In both cases your function should get the correct object.